# Listar um período de datas pelo dia da semana?

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio, algoritmo

estou precisando fazer uma função em JavaScript/jQuery que eu pegue o valor de dois campos de formato data e ele me retorne uma sequência de datas conforme eu escolha: 1ª ou 2ª terça-feira do período selecionado nos campos `data1` e `data2`. Eu não sei por onde começar, sou iniciante...

Exp:

```
data1 = 06/05/2019;
data2 = 01/10/2019;
opção = 1ª segunda-feira;


resultado = 
06/05/2019 
03/06/2019 
01/07/2019 
05/08/2019 
02/09/2019 
.... até a data final caso seja compatível com a opção selecionada.
```

Comment: Mostre o código que você já implementou e destaque a parte em que está tendo problema. Mensagem de erro e o stack trace ajudariam bastante para depurar seu código.

Comment: Então @AugustoVasques como eu afirmei no enunciado, eu não comecei nada ainda. Estava lendo sobre a função `new Date()´ e não consegui compreender muito bem o funcionamento dela quando eu digito uma data pelo input. (Eu sei que ela me mostra a data em formato completo incluindo horas, minutos.,,)! Gostaria de pelo menos achar um ponto de início!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá @rodrigo-henriques, eu fiz esse protótipo no JSFiddle para tentar ajudá-lo a compreender e melhorar o processo. Está bem "cru" e pode (e deve) ser melhorado. Veja se lhe atende. Qualquer dúvida, fique à vontade para questionar.
Link: https://jsfiddle.net/GustavoAdolfo/t61dLr5j/81/